# Печать из приложения на внешний принтер

Tags: android, принтер

Собираюсь сделать приложение Android. Я новичок, и ничего не смог нагуглить. Как вызвать печать из андроид приложения? Подскажите в какую сторону копать..

Не уверен, относится ли это к делу или нет, собираюсь делать на js + html + css + PhoneGap

Answer (score 0):

Для Cordova есть такой плагин, судя по коммитам не слишком поддерживается
https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-printer